# Durandal Compose module based on Conditional Statment

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I need to use a condition (if statement) to dynamically select which view to compose in Durandal. Is this possible? Anyone has an example that could help me start? Thank you for your help.

Comment: take a look at the durandal starter kit. http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given much context to your problem so this is a very simple (untested) example.

In your html:

```
<div data-bind="compose: myModel" />
```

In your js file:

```
define(function (require) {
    var m1 = require('module1');
    var m2 = require('module2');

    var myModel;

    myModel = (1 === 1) ? m1 : m2;

    return {
        myModel : myModel
    };
});
```

Replace 1 === 1 with your condition, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Good show Alex! Remember that every property on the compose binding is itself bindable, so you can conditionally select or change during runtime any value of any composition by using observables, logic or a combination.

Comment: Thanks Rob! It's a truly great framework you have built (again!) and I'm absolutely loving it.